# Calling function in another bash script

Tags: bash

Let's say;
Script a.sh has function f1 defined. 
Script b.sh needs to call f1 to use. 
How do I do that? I searched online, it says I have to edit some PATH vairable, but does it mean global PATH or is there any PATH specifically used only in bash?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `b.sh`:

```
source a.sh
```

That will make the function available to be called within b.sh.

The `source` command (also known as the [`.` command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)) *executes* a.sh in b.sh's shell, so if you *only* want that function, you'll have to extract it into `c.sh`, and both `a.sh` and `b.sh` will have to source c.sh